# Is $\mathbb{C}[V]^G \subset \mathbb{C}[V]$ flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, flatness

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $G$ be a finite  group acting on $V$ via $G \longrightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$. We know that $\mathbb{C}[V]^G \subset \mathbb{C}[V]$ is an integral extension.

The question is, whether it is a faithfully flat extension (it's enough to prove that it is flat). I need this to show that the induced map $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[V]) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[V]^G$ equips $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[V]^G$ with a quotient topology (I know there is an easier argument).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, see the answer to this MathOverflow post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169052/are-quotients-of-affine-schemes-by-finite-groups-faithfully-flat

Comment: @Ashwin Iyengar thanks a lot!